# Delete ArrayList from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have stored the `ArrayList` in `SharedPreferences` using the following code :

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = qarrayoff; // fetch the data
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putStringSet("SAVEDATA", new HashSet<String>(list1));
edit.commit();
```

Now I want to delete the `ArrayList` stored in `SharePreferences`. How to do that?

Comment: Just use edit.remove("SAVEDATA")

Comment: Thanks ,,It works.............

Comment: You ought to have at least gone through the `SharedPreferences` documentation before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using this code fragment:

```
edit.remove("SAVEDATA"); 
edit.commit();
```